# Clocked "Data flip flop" (DFF) implementation

Tags: logic

I am following the nice course nand2tetris and I am getting headaches trying to implement the DFF (which actually is given to us, but I want to now exactly how it works).

After some research, I found that what I need was a negative edge triggered data flip flop.

So, starting by implementing an SR gate following the and or latch:

[SR Latch using AND / OR gates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHeAa.png)

Next, thanks to CrashCourse video series, I added some extras logic gates to create an input data wire and an enable wire, let's call it a gated latch (you can see the and or latch at the right):

[Gated latch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75WbD.png)

Finally, by adding 2 gated latches in serie, I actually get it to work as aspected, I get the output copied from the input at the falling edge, and it is what I wanted.

[Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04JXq.png)

Is this circuit actually play with gates delay?
How does it actually work?
I need some explanatations and I can't find what I want.

Thank you :)